# Retrieving file contents from WinRT Camera Capture UI

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to get the compressed JPEG data out of the Camera Capture UI, but I'm getting tripped up around IInputBuffer. Here's what I've got:

```
private async void OnWebcamButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var captureUi = new CameraCaptureUI();
    var result = await captureUi.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
    var file = await result.OpenForReadAsync();
    var reader = new DataReader(file);

    byte[] data = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
    await reader.LoadAsync(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
    reader.ReadBytes(data);

    // XXX: This is always zero
    Debug.Text = String.Format("Buffer is {0} bytes", data.Length);
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you need a `DataReader` here at all. Try this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime; // for AsBuffer()
...
var file = await captureUi.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
var stream = await result.OpenForReadAsync();
byte[] data = new byte[file.Size];
await stream.ReadAsync(data.AsBuffer(), (uint)data.Length, InputStreamOptions.None);
```

Alternatively, you can use `AsStream()` extension method (from `System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensons`) to wrap WinRT `IInputStream` as `System.IO.Stream`, and then use normal .NET techniques.

Comment: Yahtzee! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: note for future readers:  the AsStream() extension method is defined in the System.IO namespace so make sure you have a `using System.IO;` statement